# Subtraction of System.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: java

```
    long rt = System.currentTimeMillis()-(1000*60*60*24*30);
```

When i convert the above variable rt to date i am not able to get expected date(i.e)30 days before. why?

Comment: Please use Date/Time api for such calculations:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html

Comment: show the code that you used to convert

Comment: It's an int overflow. Change it to `1000L`.

Answer (score 7):

`1000*60*60*24*30` results in `int` overflow, since it's larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Change it to `1000L*60*60*24*30` to use `long` instead.

For example:

```
long rt = System.currentTimeMillis()-(1000L*60*60*24*30);
System.out.println (new Date(rt));
```

prints for me:

```
Sun Feb 25 09:18:58 IST 2018
```

Comment: Damn, just beat me to it... I once used an example not dissimilar to this as a Java puzzle.